# Tensorflow: tensor binarization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to transform this dataset in such a way that each tensor has a given size `n` and that a feature at index `i` of this new tensor is set to 1 if and only if there is a `i` in the original feature (modulo n).

I hope the following example will make things clearer

Let's suppose I have a dataset like:

```
t = tf.constant([
  [0, 3, 4],
  [12, 2 ,4]])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(t)
```

I want to get (if `n` = 9)

```
t = tf.constant([
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], # index set to 1 are 0, 3 and 4
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) # index set to 1 are 2, 4, and 12%9 = 3
```

I know how to apply the modulo to a tensor, but I don't find how to do the rest of the transformation
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is similar to [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot), only for multiple values at the same time. Here is a way to do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def binarization(t, n):
    # One-hot encoding of each value
    t_1h = tf.one_hot(t % n, n, dtype=tf.bool, on_value=True, off_value=False)
    # Reduce across last dimension of the original tensor
    return tf.cast(tf.reduce_any(t_1h, axis=-2), t.dtype)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    t = tf.constant([
        [ 0,  3,  4],
        [12,  2,  4]
    ])
    t_m1h = binarization(t, 9)
    print(sess.run(t_m1h))
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the axis=-2. I understand what you are doing, but I don't understand how you come up with -2.

Comment: @taktak004 Right, so after you do `tf.one_hot` a new dimension is added at the end. However, you want to reduce across the last dimension of the input tensor (e.g. the "columns" in your example, `0, 3, 4` and `12, 2, 4`. This dimension will not be the last one in `t_1h` (because that is the new one-hot dimension), but the previous-to-last one, which can be referred to with the `-2`. I hope that makes it clearer?

Comment: @taktak004 Yes exactly the idea was that it worked either with a vector or a matrix or whatever (well actually it would fail for a scalar I think). You could also add explicit parameters for the axis that is reduced and/or the position of the new axis, but that seemed overcomplicated.

Comment: Additional question, how can I change this to handle sparse tensors ?

Comment: I created a new question as I think the approch will be totally different actually :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450218/tensorflow-dense-tensor-to-sparse-binarized-hash-trick-tensor